# How can I prevent Silverlight-based web site from taking up all the CPU in Internet Explorer?

Tags: virtualbox, internet-explorer, window, silverlight

I have a client who uses another vendor for their point of sale system. I need to periodically download reports from this system and currently the only way to do so is with Internet Explorer and it uses Silverlight. I only have a Mac, so I run Windows under VirtualBox, and this works, but after a few minutes, Windows slows to a crawl. It will take literally a full minute for a click or keypress to register.

When I look at the Mac's CPU usage, VirtualBox is using more than 200% of the CPU (2.9 GHz Quad-Core i7). Closing the IE window (and waiting a minute for the clicking of the close button to register) returns things to normal. I've confirmed with another user accessing the site under native Windows that the problem exists outside of VirtualBox.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Microsoft has removed Silverlight from everything current. You need to change the Point of Sale system to accommodate.

Comment: @Chuck Does the Windows you have under Virtual Box have Edge? If so, try that.

Comment: I have Edge, but this site only supports IE. I hear they're rewriting the site to use modern technologies, but I have no idea when that'll be.

Comment: Try to use any modern browser with changing the browser user agent to IE in Developer tool (F12).

Comment: Does it help if in the [VirtualBox Processor Tab](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-processor) you reduce  Execution Cap? The default setting is 100%, meaning unlimited. Or you could use [BES](http://mion.faireal.net/BES/) in the VM for IE (or other).

Comment: @Biswapriyo, well that was an interesting idea, but I tried it, and even though Silverlight is installed, Edge doesn't recognize it, and neither does Firefox or Chrome.